# Are there BDD/TDD tools for developing in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, testing, tdd, automated-tests, bdd

I am responsible for rewriting an internal tool for my company. I am currently reworking the most time consuming step to run faster which should give me time to re-think the design of the application for a full rewrite as the interstitial version will meet the current needs.

I really want to take this opportunity to implement this code using BDD/TDD but I am new to this method of programming in general and especially within the context of .NET. Are there BDD/TDD tools available for .NET? What resources should I look at?

Thank you very much in advance!

Ashish

Answer (score 3):

As one of the members joked when we discussed BDD at one of our alt.net oresund meetings: "there are more BDD frameworks for .Net, than there are people using them" ;-)

When starting with BDD, or having executable acceptance tests, I recommend to first understand "[what's in a story](http://dannorth.net/whats-in-a-story)" (i.e. how to define the requirements.

Having nailed a few of those, **then** you can go find a tool that fits your particular needs in your particular context.

At my current project we chose [StoryQ](http://www.codeplex.com/storyq) as our BDD tool since we were already using NUnit and TestDriven.Net, and didn't have to add anything but an assembly reference (no separate test runner, etc).

At the aforementioned alt.net meeting, one of the members demonstrated using [Cucumber under IronRuby for an app written in C#](http://blog.thomaslundstrom.com/search/label/Cucumber).

Many people appreciate the way Cucumber turns plain English into requirements, why that might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper, Nunit, xUnit, MBUnit, are just some of the things that spring to mind.

Resharper because of the nice testrunner and the neat refactorings it can do. (not free)

NUnit because I use that now. (free)

NCover because sometimes you miss a spot. (not free anymore).

Structuremap because IoC/Di is a given. (free)

Rhino mocks because you need to stub and mock. (free)

ASP.Net MVC if you need webdevelopment.

That is just  my current stack.

I forgot a few others. But most things that work in C# will now work in VB.Net. And they will work even better in VB.Net 10

Comment: Thank you very much @chrissie1. I will definitely look into NUnit & Rhino. Since I am a beginner, are there resources that you can recommend which will help me learn the fundamentals specific to these tools beyond the documentation that is available on their respective websites?

Comment: I have a blog http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/All/?disp=authdir&author=7 where i post things about VB.Net. But VB.Net bloggers are very rare. You should look for C# examples instead and try to convert them. Not that it will always work especially not the lambda things.